# Python: min heap swap count

Tags: python, indexing, heap, min-heap

Although there are lots of questions that have already been asked and answered regarding heap implementation in python, I was unable to find any practical clarifications about indexes. So, allow me to ask one more heap related question.

I'm trying to write a code that transforms a list of values into a min-heap and saves swapped indexes. Here is what I have so far:

```
def mins(a, i, res):
    n = len(a)-1
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2
    if not (i >= n//2 and i <= n):
        if (a[i] > a[left] or a[i] > a[right]):

            if a[left] < a[right]:
                res.append([i, left])
                a[i], a[left] = a[left], a[i]
                mins(a, left, res)
            
            else:
                res.append([i, right])
                a[i], a[right] = a[right], a[i]
                mins(a, right, res)

def heapify(a, res):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range(n//2, -1, -1):
        mins(a, i, res)
    return res


a = [7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
res = heapify(a, [])

print(a)
print(res)
```

Expected output:

```
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
res = [[2, 5], [1, 4], [0, 2], [2, 5]]
```

What I get:

```
a = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]
res = [[1, 4], [0, 1], [1, 3]]
```

It's clear that there is something wrong with indexation in the above script. Probably something very obvious, but I just don't see it. Help out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code:

- In `heapify` the first node that has a child, is at index `(n - 2)//2`, so use that as start value of the `range`.
- In `mins` the condition `not (i >= n//2 and i <= n)` does not make a distinction between the case where the node has just one child or two. And `i==n//2` should really be allowed when `n` is odd. Because then it has a left child. It is so much easier to just compare the value of `left` and `right` with `n`. It is also confusing that in `heapify` you define `n` as `len(a)`, while in `mins` you define it as one less. This is really good for confusing the reader of your code!

To avoid code duplication (the two blocks where you swap), introduce a new variable that is set to either `left` or `right` depending on which one has the smaller value.

Here is a correction:

```
def mins(a, i, res):
    n = len(a)
    left = 2 * i + 1
    right = 2 * i + 2
    if left >= n:
        return
    child = left
    if right < n and a[right] < a[left]:
        child = right
    if a[child] < a[i]:  # need to swap
        res.append([i, child])
        a[i], a[child] = a[child], a[i]
        mins(a, child, res)

def heapify(a, res):
    n = len(a)
    for i in range((n - 2)//2, -1, -1):
        mins(a, i, res)
    return res
```

Comment: It's all good, except  that `(n-2)`  specification in `heapify` is not required for this code. It works fine with just `n//2`.

Comment: Yes, but it is not so exact. You see, it will also work with with just `n-1`, `n` or even `2*n`. ;-) A heap structure is all about performance, so spending an iteration with no effect should be avoided.

Comment: We still have to go through neighbours when comparing elements, if I understand how it works correctly. When running your code with n <= 10*5, both `n//2` and `(n-2)//2` perform roughly under the same time. I didn't make exact measurements, but i believe in this case it's the more simple the code is, the better. However, I appreciate your desire for optimization.

Comment: Any way, if you need better performance, use the built-in `heapq` package.